# How can I vertically centralize geom_text output on a stacked bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my dataset:

```r
structure(list(title = c("Fried Anchovies with Sage", "Anchovies Appetizer With Breadcrumbs & Scallions", 
"Carrots, Cauliflower And Anchovies", "Bap Story: Stir Fried Anchovies (Myulchi Bokkeum)", 
"Fried Anchovies", "Tomato & Anchovies With Bread Crumbs, Basil & Red Onion   Recip", 
"Marinated Fresh Anchovies: Alici Marinate", "Marinated Boquerones", 
"Spaghetti With Walnuts And Anchovies", "Roasted Peppers with Boquerones"
), pricePerServing = c(5.6051, 0.8206, 4.38, 8.1122, 1.505, 0.8603, 
5.5005, 4.1332, 0.9284, 0.5844), healthScore = c(29, 4, 63, 70, 
6, 14, 33, 82, 45, 48), readyInMinutes = c(45L, 15L, 45L, 45L, 
15L, 45L, 420L, 45L, 12L, 4500L), veryHealthy = c("False", "False", 
"True", "True", "False", "False", "False", "True", "False", "False"
), dairyFree = c("True", "True", "True", "True", "True", "True", 
"True", "True", "False", "True"), dishType = c("lunch", "antipasti", 
"lunch", "lunch", "antipasti", "side dish", "lunch", "lunch", 
"lunch", "side dish"), healthy = c(0.752433090024331, 0.752433090024331, 
0.247566909975669, 0.247566909975669, 0.752433090024331, 0.752433090024331, 
0.752433090024331, 0.247566909975669, 0.752433090024331, 0.752433090024331
), diary = c(0.423965936739659, 0.423965936739659, 0.423965936739659, 
0.423965936739659, 0.423965936739659, 0.423965936739659, 0.423965936739659, 
0.423965936739659, 0.576034063260341, 0.423965936739659), percent = c(0.370250606305578, 
0.370250606305578, 0.587223587223587, 0.587223587223587, 0.370250606305578, 
0.370250606305578, 0.370250606305578, 0.587223587223587, 0.629749393694422, 
0.370250606305578)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to make a percent stacked barplot but I cannot vertically centralize my text. `position_stack(vjust = 0.5)` does not work.
My code is:

```r
  ggplot(foods, aes(x=veryHealthy, y=diary, width=healthy , fill = dairyFree,
                    label = percent)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity', position="fill") +
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
    facet_grid(~veryHealthy, scales = "free", space = "free") +
    geom_text(stat="unique", position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

I get this result:
[image]
How can I centralize the geom_text output here?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't get the same output as you when I run your data and plot.

Comment: that said,  you can try to play with the `vjust` argument or change to `position_fill`.

Comment: @Maël I tried both, I think ```stat=unique``` is making the labels on each column have the same height.

Comment: Yes, and I think your data set must be rearranged a bit; because we don't get the same output as the image.

Comment: @Maël I could not put all my data here because stack overflow would not let me submit my question. my result is on all the data

Comment: You can use a sample of it that includes every possibility. In your toy data, dairyFree is only T when veryHealth is T, and the percent value do not correspond to the true value.

Comment: @Maël the very first row is opposite of what you said, dairyFree is T and veryHealthy is F.

Comment: @Hamed What exactly are you trying to do here? The text in your graphs seemed to be centered already? Do you want the two graphs to be the same width?

Comment: @neuron no it is not centered, pay attention: the left labels are above the center and right labels are below the center.

Comment: @Hamed Instead of telling me to pay attention, why don't you put the explanation into your question so we don't have to guess what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to work with a summary table, so as your data provided is not complete, I created a small sample summary table to plot. Your task to get your data to a format like below.

```
foods <- data.frame(
  veryHealthy = c(F, F, T, T),
  dairyFree = c(T, F, T, F),
  percent = c(0.37, 0.63, 0.59, 0.41),
  healthy = c(0.75, 0.75, 0.25, 0.25)
)

ggplot(foods, aes(x = veryHealthy, y = percent, width = healthy, fill = dairyFree)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position = "fill") +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  facet_grid(~ veryHealthy, scales = "free", space = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks you are right.